# Standardised path coefficient values in a SEM multigroup comparison are very close and yet one is significant for one group while the other is not?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, structural-equation-modeling

I am testing the hypothesized effect in a model using SEM A -> B between two groups. The results of the standardised path coefficients (SPC) are Group 1: spc = 0.334 p < 0.001;
Group 2: spc = 0.316 p = 0.181. I would have expected the effect of group  2 to also be significant although it is worth noting that there are differences in the group sizes (group 1 = 72 group 2= 189). Is this an issue caused by the difference in the group sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard error (and hence the p-value) depend on the group size.

It's also possible that other things vary between the groups, such as relationships with other variables.